# Creating GCP vm instance snapshot in automated way

Tags: snapshot, google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement of creating snapshot of vm instance in GCP on the daily basis and we want to keep last 5 snapshots.Is there any way to do same in GCP in automated fashion?

Comment: Because it can flush the buffers I would suggest using gcloud on the VM.

Comment: (continued)

Create the snapshot using: `gcloud compute disks snapshot --guest-flush [DISK_NAME]'  I don't think that there is any way to do lifecycle management on snapshots so use the `gcloud compute snapshots` command to tag and delete.  If you use _cron_ and _--snapshot-names=_ in a logical way with the guest name and date it should be fairly easy to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this using following steps

1. Log in to your Google Cloud account. On your Google Cloud  dashboard and click the hamburger menu in the upper left-hand corner of the screen.
2. After that, Navigate to Compute Engine >> Snapshots.
3. Then click on “Create snapshot” button.

Configuring Snapshot Schedule

4. Name: Give any name as you wise to store the snapshot.
5. Region: select where you want to set up your snapshot schedule.
   Go to your VM instance or Disk page and check the zone details.
6. Snapshot location : select where you want to store your VM snapshot. Choose default if you don’t want to pay any fees.
7. Schedule frequency – choose how often you want to take a backup from daily, weekly, hourly.
8. Auto-delete snapshots - how many last snapshots you want to keep at any time.
9. Deletion rule – what should happen if you delete your VM instance. If you choose Keep snapshots then your backups are retained permanently unless you delete them manually. 
   If you choose “Delete snapshots older than [x] days then your backup get automatically deleted after [x] days.
10. Finally, Click Create to create the snapshot schedule.

Refer to the link.
[GCP SNAPSHOT SCHEDULES](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots?authuser=1&_ga=2.245954500.-1373944797.1588160130&_gac=1.16577604.1588343671.Cj0KCQjwka_1BRCPARIsAMlUmEoYnSJSeng1igXd_3VjMETyKBRvrx-BPyJXNzL1bStf48DSpo2OICQaAkytEALw_wcB)